Do any non-invertible functions satisfy $(f \circ g)(x)=x$
Is there a non one-to-one function $f$ such that , when composed with another function $g$ it gives back the identity function?
I am not referring to inverse functions . Because from the definition , for a function to be invertible it needs to be one-to-one. For example obviously for :
$f(x)=e^x , g(x)=\log(x)$ the composition of the two $(f \circ g)(x)=f(g(x))= e^{\log(x)}=x$
All I was able to come up with was $f(x)=x^2 , g(x)=\sqrt{x} $ and $f(g(x))=(\sqrt{x})^2=x$
But these functions are still inverses for restricted values of $x$
So a better phrasing for the question would be:
Do any non-invertible functions satisfy $(f \circ g)(x)=x$ ?
Edit.
I'm also not talking about functions that are defined to be the inverse of another like the Lambert $W$ function. I am searching for a closed form answer. Any help would be appreciated!
Edit 2 :
I'm suspecting what I am asking is impossible , how would one go about formally proving it?

yes : $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^+$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ and $g:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$ defined by $g(x)=\sqrt x$. Then $(f\circ g)(x)=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^+$, but $f$ is not invertible...

For $x \in \mathbb{R} _+$ , $x^2$ is the inverse of $\sqrt{x}$ though. Is what I am asking non logical ? I'm starting to get very confused.

You can also consider $g:C\big([0, 1]\big) \rightarrow C^1\big([0, 1]\big)$, $g(u)(t) := \int^t_0 u(s)~\mathrm{d}s$ and $f:C^1\big([0, 1]\big) \rightarrow C\big([0, 1]\big)$, $f(u)(t) := u'(t)$. $f$ is not injective (constant functions map onto zero), but still, $(f\circ g)(u) = u$. This is very abstract, so probably worthless to you, but what I want to say is that you can even use linear mappings $f, g$ (it has to be on an infinite-dimensional space however) for such constructions. There is this concept of the one-sided inverse.

One of my favorite examples to repeat... consider the space of infinite sequences $\Bbb R^\Bbb N$.  Consider the right-shift $r$ operator that maps a sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ to the sequence $(0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ and the left shift operator $\ell$ which maps a sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ to the sequence $(a_2,a_3,a_4,\dots)$.  Here, you can have $(\ell\circ r)((a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)) = (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ but you have $(r\circ \ell)((a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)) = (0,a_2,a_3,\dots)$

@JMoravitz Very good example that everyone should know!

@HyperbolicPDEfriend One question , what exactly does $g(u)(t)$ mean? Does this function have 2 variables ? or only $t$ ?

$u$ is a function $u:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If you plug that into $g$, you get a new function $g(u):[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For every $t \in [0, 1]$, this function can be evaluated with $g(u) (t) = \int^t_0 u(s)~\mathrm{d}s$.

Alright , thanks for explaining !

The functional equation insures that $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective. Restricting $f$ to the range of $g$ gives you a pair of inverse functions.
(Incidentally, I remember this as the "in-sur" ("insure") principle: If a composition is injective, the function applied first must be injective. If it's surjective, the function applied second must be surjective. Conversely, any injective function with a non-empty domain has a left inverse, and any surjective function has a right inverse.)
(It works even better if you write your compositions left-to-right, which unfortunately is not the standard convention.)
One half of the "insure" principle is easy, when stated contrapositively. If $g$ is not injective, say $g(a)=g(b)$ for $a\neq b$, then $f\circ g$ is also not injective for any $f$, because $f(g(a))=f(g(b))$. Likewise if $f$ is not surjective, say $f(y)\neq z$ for some $z$ in the codomain of $f$ and all $y$ in $f$'s domain, then $f(g(x))\neq z$ for all $x$ in $g$'s domain (which is also $f\circ g$'s domain). So $f\circ g$ is not surjective.
By the way, I'm assuming the category Set, where the morphisms from $A$ to $B$ are all the functions $f:A\to B$. In other categories things are not always so simple. The appropriate generalizations of "injective" and surjective are probably "monic" and "epic":

We say $g$ is monic if for all $h_1$ and $h_2$, $g\circ h_1 = g\circ h_2$ implies $h_1=h_2$. We say $g$ is split monic if $g$ has a left inverse, $f\circ g = \text{id}$.
We say $f$ is epic if for all $h_1$ and $h_2$, $h_1\circ f=h_2\circ f$ implies $h_1=h_2$. We say $f$ is split epic if $f$ has a right inverse, $f\circ g=\text{id}$.

It's to show that in Set, monic iff injective, and epic iff surjective. In Set, split epic iff epic, and except for the weird case of a function with an empty domain, split monic iff monic.
But this doesn't hold in some other categories. You say you are looking for "closed forms", so I suspect you're not concerned with functions in general. I don't know of a category whose morphisms are exactly the "closed forms" (howeve that's defined), but perhaps looking at the category of analytic functions between analytic manifolds might be a decent approximation to what you want.
For more about monics and epics, Leinster's Basic Category Theory is an excellent reference. (Available here. Solutions to almost all exercises, and a section further discussing monics and epics in various categories, here.)

Consider the following proposition:

Proposition. Let $X,Y$ be sets and let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. The following statements hold:

$f$ is injective if and only if it has a left inverse.
$f$ is surjective if and only if it has a right inverse.


This proposition means that any $f:X\to Y$ which is surjective but not injective will have another function $g:Y\to X$ such that $(f\circ g)(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$. Furthermore, there can be no left inverse of $f$ if it is not injective. To give you an easy example, take $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ given by $f(x)=x^2$. Then $f$ is clearly not injective, as it is even, but it is surjective, and a right inverse is $g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$, as then
$$(f\circ g)(x)=\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2=x$$
for all $x\in[0,\infty)$. This $f$ does not, however, have a left inverse, as if it did have a left inverse $h:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$, then we would have that
$$x=(h\circ f)(x)=h(x^2)=h((-x)^2)=(h\circ f)(-x)=-x$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, which clearly is not true.
If you want an easy example where $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, take $f(x)=x^3-x$. I'll leave it to you to check the details for this one.
